# How to check if element exist in three lists using scala?

Tags: scala

I have following three lists:

```
List((List(vmnic2),"VM Network",10,"vSwitch0"), (List("vmnic2"),"Management Network",0,"vSwitch0"))
List(List("vmnic2"))
List("VM Network 2", "VM Network 3", "VM Network")
```

I want to do following:

1) I want to check whether first list contains second list and 
2) Any of element from third list matches with second value in any element of first list.

From above three list I want output as

```
List(List("vmnic2"),"VM Network",10,"vSwitch0")
```

How do I get above output using scala??

Comment: Have you considered using case classes instead of lists? They seem to work better than these heterogenous (`Any` Lists).

Comment: Actually I am using case classes for it. I have three different classes for these three lists..

Comment: Your example is not valid scala code. That makes it hard for people to understand what you want and help you.

Comment: What  do you mean by "contains" in your first query? That the head of the second list appears as the first element of one of the lists in the first list?

Comment: @paul you are right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
list1.filter(e =>
  e._1.intersect(list2(0)) == list2(0)  // check if first element contains second list
    && list3.contains(e._2))            // check if third list contains second element
```

Comment: Not in your example it isn't. if it can't be known to contain Lists of something, it's a bit more difficult. Please add to your example enough to demonstrate it's a List[Any]

Comment: @Vishwas So what means `first list contains second list`?

Comment: And if it's List[Any] attempts to pattern match any lists it does contain are defeated by type erasure. I think your design needs re-visiting.

Comment: @sergey: how to match if I change list2 to List(("vmnic2","vSwitch0"),("vmnic1",vSwitch1)). In short how do I match above given list to list1 instead of using list2(0)) == list2(0)